# Consultas a BBDD con usuario logueado con JWT en Spring Boot y Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, rest, jwt

Tal vez me podrían ayudar con esto? Estoy haciendo una api rest usando en el back Spring Boot y en el front la consumo con jQuery/Javascript, he ido bien hasta que me topado con el tema del login.

Ya he implementado en mi back la autenticacion y el login y haciendo pruebas con postman me da los resultados que espero introduciendo el token en la cabecera para realizar la peticion correctamente , un ejemplo de ello seria llamada al endpoint **localhost:8080/ofertas** que previamente fue configurado para que solo lo puedan ver los usuarios logados.

Mi duda viene cuando en un endpoint similar al anterior, ejemplo **localhost:8080/{idUsuario}/ofertas**,

**¿cómo puedo hacer para que en el front una vez autenticado me muestre los datos que pertenecen a ese usuario que está usando ese JWT, sin tener que yo este introduciendo el id manualmente?**. Como dije antes si hago la peticion por postman introduciendolo manualmente **ej -> localhost:8080/1/ofertas** obtengo los datos.

Adjunto mi código

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/linktickas/auth")
public class AuthControlador {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio;

    @Autowired
    private RolRepositorio rolRepositorio;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;

    @Autowired
    private EstudianteService estudianteService;

    /*
     * @Autowired private JavaMailSender mail;
     */

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthControlador.class);

    @PostMapping("/iniciarSesion")

    public ResponseEntity<JWTAuthResponseDto> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDTO) {

        logger.info("INICIAR SESION");

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getEmail(), loginDTO.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        // obtenemos el token del jwtTokenProvider
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.generarToken(authentication);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JWTAuthResponseDto(token));
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/estudiantes")
public class EstudianteControllerImpl{

    @GetMapping("/{id}/mis-ofertas") //AQUI ES DONDE DEBERIA IR EL ID DEL USUARIO
    public ResponseEntity<List<?>> misOfertas(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(StreamSupport
                .stream(ofertaService.buscarOfertasDeEstudiantePorSuId(id).spliterator() , false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        
    }
```

//EDIT
Datos del token que obtengo:

[image: Datos del token que obtengo]

Comment: Puedes modificar la url para no enviar el ID y en vez de eso lo obtienes del JWT directamente. Tu JWT debería tener la ID del usuario obviamente, además de sus permisos/roles

Comment: Entonces la url que me propones deberia ser **localhost:8080/{elidDelUsuarioQueVaEnElToken}/mis-ofertas? Algo asi? En mi token como mencionas he estado introduciendo correo y roles, edito la pregunta para que se pueda ver

Comment: He añadido la imagen en la que se aprecia la info que le paso al token

Comment: No, la url debería quedar directamente `localhost:8080/mis-ofertas`, o como prefiero yo `localhost:8080/me/ofertas`, y con un filtro en las llamadas a `/me` lo que hago es coger el token del header y setear los valores que necesito en custom headers de la llamada, de esa manera en los controller tengo disponibles todos los datos que necesite del usuario directamente en los headers y puedo inyectarlos al controller :) [Algo así](http://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/) funcionaría, por ejemplo. De esa manera en tu controller siempre vas a tener la ID y lo que quieras